# Config SLF4J in jar file

Tags: java, slf4j

I have my own jar file which is used as a library for my main application. I need to set SLF4J as my logger and configure it in my jar.

- Write logs into a file
- Set other configurations in a property file

When it is googled, there are samples for web apps. Any one let me know how to do above functionalities or mention any useful resource.

Answer (score 3):

For a library, you should only include `slf4j-api.jar`. This means that in your code, you should only use classes within SLF4J's API, i.e. `LoggerFactory` and `Logger`.

Your library should not define anything else regarding logging. It's the responsibility of the application that uses your library to define the underlying logging implementation (logback, log4j, jcl, etc) and include the necessary *bindings*, as well as the underlying logging platform's configuration, such as a `logback.xml` file.

Please refer to the [SLF4J manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) for further reference.

Answer (score 3):

To log something using slf4j, you must include the slf4j-api jar in your application. This is the bare minimum that is nessesary for slf4j logging. If using maven, it can be included in the pom as shown below

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.10</version>
</dependency>
```

However the default logging behavior in slf4j is very simple. In nearly all circumstances you will want to send slf4j logs to a logging framework, which can perform more complex logging. There are several jars that can be included to accomplish this. I use log4j, so the examples below are for that framework. In order to log over log4j, slf4j-log4j12 jar is needed.

Pom dependancy

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.10</version>
</dependency>
```

From there all slf4j logs will be redirected to log4j, which will work normally. Configure it through a log4j.properties file. The below example log4j.properties will log things both to the console, and to the `/tmp/logfile.log` file. remove the console appender to only log to the file.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file
 
# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/tmp/logfile.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

If you want to log with a different framework, include the appropriate jar, and configure the underlying framework as you otherwise would.

Comment: Please let me know where this file should be located and how to bind this file to the SLF4J factory ?  If I don't need, log4j and pure SLF4J logging is only needed, how to modify this ?

Comment: @Débora put the file in your `src/main/resources` folder, if you want the settings hard-coded into the jar. Alternatively, put it into a folder on the file-system, and include that folder on the classpath of the jar when running it. The binding is automatically handled by the slf4j-log4j12 dependancy. The only potential difficulty is if you have included multiple jars that bind slf4j to different frameworks, in which case it will pick one essentially at random. Make sure to include only the log4j binding, and things should automaticlaly work themselves out.

Answer (score -3):

SLF4J is not a logger, therefore you cannot configure anything. Use Logback.